# Where can I find a list of all the cards in Elder Sign?

Tags: elder-sign

I'm looking for a breakdown of the common item, unique item and spell cards so I know what my chances are when buying certain cards. I've done a bit of googling and have not come up with anything.

Comment: Why don't you just look at the cards next time you're setting up the game??

Comment: I think it would help to give a more specific example of what you are looking for when you say "Know what my chances are".

Comment: @bwarner, I only played the game once long ago, so I didn't know he meant something than what he said. Could you fix the question, please?

Answer (score 1):

Someone over on boardgame geek added a list of [all cards for all expansions](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/120191/elder-sign-all-cards-all-expansions) since I originally asked the question and did my search.

Answer (score -2):

Board game geek has [Elder Sign](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/100423/elder-sign) listed. One of files in the game listing should have the information that you're looking for. I'll point out that the game also has a number of expansion packs.

Comment: Hi Max! Thanks for attempting to help out on an old, unanswered question. However, your answer doesn't really provide any extra direction. If you look on the site, find the desired content and provide a link, that would be much more useful!

Comment: I was trying to teach you how to fish. :-( BGG has more information about any sort of game than any other site on the web.

Comment: You're not wrong, but the purpose of the site is to collect questions with useful answers that will help anyone looking at the same issue (an encyclopaedia rather than a forum). Unfortunately "the information should be on another site if you search for it" doesn't match what we think of as a good answer, even if it might be a more useful activity for some people.

Comment: I had checked. I knew the file was there for the base game. I didn't check all the expansions.